# Removing duplicates and summing up quantity

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

```
var name = new Array();
var amount = new Array();
name[0]="Peter";
amount[0]="50";
name[1]="John";
amount[1]="10";
name[2]="John";
amount[2]="20";
name[3]="Peter";
amount[3]="20";
name[4]="Mary";
amount[4]="40";
```

I have something like the above. My question is, how can I create a function to eliminate all the duplicates and sum up the values for each person in the arrays? Below is the results I am looking for.

For example:

```
Peter 70
John  30
Mary  40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
var sum = {};
var i;
for (i = 0; i < amount.length; i++) {
  var name = name[i];
  var oldSum = sum[name];
  if (typeof oldSum === 'undefined') {
    oldSum = 0;
  }
  sum[name] = oldSum + amount[i];
}
```

Now the object `sum` will have a property for every name in `name` and the value of the property will be the sum of the amounts which had the that name

To print it out try the following

```
for (var prop in sum) {
  if (sum.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    console.log(prop + " " sum[prop]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works nicely. How if I wanted to print the last name and perhaps sum up another array, such as Quantity?

Comment: @wvxvw the value `sum` is used in a very confined scope hence I can safely assert that `undefined` is a non-legal value.  In this scope it can have numeric values or nothing. I don't understand your *slow* argument. Using `key in map` then reading the value requires 2 lookups per iteration of the loop while my solution has 1 lookup.

Comment: @JaredPar , how do I add in another array to sum up,amount2, for eg: 
name[0]="Peter";
amount[0]="50";
amount2[0]="20";

name[1]="John";
amount[1]="10";
amount2[1]="30";

name[2]="John";
amount[2]="20";
amount2[2]="50";

name[3]="Peter";
amount[3]="20";
amount2[3]="40";

name[4]="Mary";
amount[4]="40";
amount2[4]="5";

Comment: @wvxvw using `key in prop` also causes a branch and forces a double look up of the value (the `in` test and subsequent look up for positive cases). The double lookup will far out way a simple branch which is itself unlikely to have a significant perf impact here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you actually want to modify the Arrays, or just collect the results.

Here's a way to collect the results in an Object.

```
var result = name.reduce(function(res, n, i) {
    res[n] = (res[n] + +amount[i]) || +amount[i];
    return res;
}, {});
```

The `.reduce()` method requires a shim for IE8 and lower.

Result is:

```
{
    "Peter": 70,
    "John": 30,
    "Mary": 40
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = {};
for( var i=name.length; i--; ) {
  result[name[i]] = result[ name[i] ] ? (result[name[i]] + parseInt( amount[i], 10 )) : parseInt( amount[i], 10 );
}
console.log( result );
```

returns

```
{ Mary=40, Peter=70, John=30 }
```

The `parseInt()` is just necessary as you give the `amount[]` values as strings.

`result` after the call is an object holding the summed up values, where the key is the entry from `name[]` and the value is from `amount[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
tally=[];
for(i=0;i<name.length;i++) {
  if(tally[name[i]]==undefined){
    tally[name[i]]=parseInt(amount[i]);
  }else{
    tally[name[i]]+=parseInt(amount[i]);
  }
}
```